# Do I need autovacuum for INSERT's-only partitioned table?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I use PG13 with timescaledb 2.4. I have one big table with retention policy 1 week. There are bullk INSERT's, some SELECT's and no UPDATE/DELETE's. After 1 week I suppose chunks are dropped.

Is this space need to be vacuum-ed? Why timescaledb-tune autovacuum settings are so aggressive?

```
autovacuum_naptime = 10
autovacuum_max_workers = 10
```

Can I disable autovacuum for this table in my case?

Answer (score 2):

You should never disable autovacuum. Configure it correctly. For one, disabling autovacuum also disables autoanalyze, and you will end up with horrible execution plans and badly performing queries.

If you never `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, and your data don't live long, there would be only one reason for autovacuum to run: to get efficient index-only scans. `VACUUM` maintains the “visibility map”, and index-only scans are only efficient if most blocks are marked “all visible” there.

If you don't need index-only scans, and you are running v13 and above, you can disable autovacuum by setting [`autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-INSERT-THRESHOLD) to -1.

Setting `autovacuum_naptime` to 10 is silly, but increasing `autovacuum_max_workers` makes sense if you have a lot of partitions. Even if you don't need `VACUUM`, you may need autovacuum to `ANALYZE` many partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use exactly index-only scans. What do you suggest for autovacuum_naptime ?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Nevermind, I only saw the link to the database config variable and didn't realise that you can also set them as [storage parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS)